# componentWillRecieveProps current props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a component of the form

`<MyComponent sources={this.state.sources} />`

When the component is first mounted, `sources={{}}`, an empty dictionary. Since this component is wrapping an existing Javascript library, I'm implementing a custom diffing function. In order for this diffing function to work the first time, it needs to know that `this.props.sources = {}` the first time and `this.props.sources= { ... stuff ... }` on subsequent updates. The React docs say that `componentWillRecieveProps` is not called on initial mount, but I'm trying to do the following:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(this.props.sources)
}
```

After initializing `MyComponent` with `sources={{}}`, I pass it some `sources={... stuff ...}`, and I expected, `this.props.sources` inside `componentWillReceiveProps` to be `{}` since the `nextProps` haven't yet been updated. However, `this.props.sources` returns `{... stuff ...}`, the most recent props passed in.

Comment: All works as you want, or i didn't understand you?[https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/71598/](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/71598/)

Comment: @Andrew thanks, but this works because you are setting the state in `componentDidMount` - I was expecting it to work without setting state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because passing by reference in js.
In your parent component you do: `<MyComponent sources={this.state.sources} />` and I think you also did `this.state.sources.push(something);` if you do that, that is the wrong way to change state, it will break the reference compare for child component `MyComponent`  Could you make sure u did not modify the original parent's state?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.sources
```

Inside of your componentWillReceiveProps method is likely referring to the parent class's props, not the incoming props.  Try logging

```
nextProps.sources
```

instead and see if that's more in line with what you expected.

Comment: They both result in the same thing